# Gunn oscillator's frequency drift

Tags: rf, oscillator

Why does the frequency increase once the Gunn oscillator is disconnected from the power supply? Is it because more and more electrons move to the lower valley, where their mobility decreases?

Comment: depends on mode http://gorgia.no-ip.com/phd/html/thesis/phd_html/node3.html#sec:theory-gunn-oscillators-modes

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Suppose it's TE10, and the Gunn is connected to a 7V power supply, operating at about 8GHz. Is the explanation I suggested applicable in this case?

Comment: insuffient info . did you read that link?